# Prevent fuzzyfinder loading files in NERDTree window

Tags: vim, nerdtree, fuzzyfinder

I'm using both fuzzyfinder and NERDTree for vim. When my cursor is in the Window that NERDTree resides in and I use fuzzyfinder, it will open a file in the NERDTree window.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and force files not to open in the NERDTree window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use a custom mapping or override the default FuzzyFinder mapping to start it. In there you can then check for an open NERDTree, and jump to the previous window (or maybe close NERDTree), like this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F5> :<C-u>if exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) == winnr() <Bar> wincmd p <Bar> endif <Bar> FufBuffer<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if [this script (at the bottom of the page](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/NERDTree-and-FuzzyFinder-how-to-force-open-in-main-buffers-window-td2180652.html) works for you.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with having alternative navigation methods. (I even use FuzzyFinder, NERDTree, MRU, _and_ MruMenu!) More power to you!

Comment: I second @IngoKarkat, I don't see anything wrong with what I'm trying to achieve, I actually use Command-T, FuzzyFinder and NERDTree and it works very well for me. On another note, I've tried that script and it doesn't work.

Comment: Command-T and FuzzyFinder do essentially the same things: having two plugins with so much overlap seems superfluous to me.